# Array yielding results AND an error at the same time

Tags: php, arrays, split

this is working on my main site, so while i was working with putting images in, it decided not to work. as you will see, the errors it produces are phantoms, yet it halts execution. All I am doing is extracting the MONTH regardless of comments, its is not the topic of this issue. watch: (it could be any array - remember its working live)

```
$date = "2011-06-06 15:22:30";

$date = explode(" ",$date);     //splits time and date
echo $date[0]."<br/>"; // prints 2011-06-06

$date = explode("-",trim($date[0]));  //split ymd
echo $date[1]."<br/>";  // prints 06 *** no error here

$num = $date[1]; // now this doesnt work??!!??
echo "num: ".$date[1]; // prints 06 AND Undefined offset: 1 in....
```

question: how can `echo "num: ".$date[1];` yield a correct result AND have an undefined offset at the same time? I do my work locally (of course) then once working I upload it. But I can't upload my new work until I figure out why this array is being a stinker!

here is the puzzler. this exact code is working live perfect. I was adding images on a completely different page. the code above is 150% non related to the work I am doing, it just is not working.

original code (live) that is working fine:

```
$date = explode(" ",$date);     //splits time and date
$date = explode("-",$date[0]);  //split ymd

$date[1] = $month[$date[1]];
return $date;
```

Comment: `Undefined offset: 1 in` it's just error for another code. I checked this code - no warnings and notices.

Comment: What line does the "undefined offset" error point to? The `$num = $date[1];` line or the `echo "num: ".$date[1];` one? And could you please post the exact error?

Comment: I am unable to duplicate this error on my localhost. Can you confirm that the error is with this part of code and not something afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

That code works fine for me, are you sure the notice is actually from that line? That said, the following code will accomplish the same, but (a heck of a lot) easier:

```
<?php
$date = new Datetime( "2011-06-06 15:22:30" ); 
echo $date->format( 'm' );
```

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/11/funcitondate.jpg/ There is a screen of the code (yes i like yours better, i have a reson for not doing oop at the moment), it errors out on line 285. BUT i just ran it again, now no errors I DIDN'T TOUCH A THING. I think this thing is possessed! for 3hrs was erroring out on line 285. "undefined offset.

Comment: In which case I get it: you're calling $date[1] = $month[$date[1]]; however, if the original $date has "1", instead of "01", it would spit out "NOTICE: Undefined offset 1", which is correct as January in your case is "01". Is that it?

Comment: nm its still erroring out. well when i echo it, it is correct: 06 not 6 so the month array has to be in the format '06' inorder for it to work. remember the above code is working fine live. its not working locally

Comment: oh and its not erroring out on the MONTH its not even there yet, its erroring out BEFORE that on $date[1]. saying that $date[1] is a bad offset, when you echo it, it shows correct.

Comment: @radu the code is not getting that far. its erroring BEFORE the month saying that $date[1] <b>"...Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in..."</b>

Comment: In which case I'm fresh out of ideas. Your PHP must be broken, if all you say here is accurate :)

Comment: @berry its haunted LOL. I think I'll do a reboot, I agree with you, this is MOST odd. im using version 5.3.x so not sure whats up. the date[1] should not produce an error as
and look at this error if i print out the array:   Array ( [0] => 2011 [1] => 06 [2] => 06 )
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in F:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: You could try debugging it. Make a small new file with just the problem code (the function), call it just like you would in the full code, and isolate the problem. If you come to the conclusion that the array does indeed contain index `1` yet you get the "undefined offset: 1" error, then it's something wrong with PHP. But just make sure you isolate the code in a separate script, so there's no chance of something else interfering.

Comment: but its silly. its working flawlessly live. and there is NO offset 6, just 0,1,2 (btw I just rebooted, no effect). The above code is a function (check the screen shot) so its already isolated. the only variable passed is the date string in the format of **Y-m-d H:i:s** I'll keep hammering away at it, I am sure its something small. when I figure it out, i'll post it here for future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: OK New code. Works great. I spread out the variables and used OOP: ` function parseDate($tdate)
    {
       $date = new DateTime($tdate);
       $zdate[0] = $date->format( 'Y' );
       $zdate[1] = $date->format( 'F' );
       $zdate[2] = $date->format( 'd' );
    
        return $zdate;
    }`
apparently it didnt like using the same name variables. This is an open source I am making for a few people with little php so trying to keep it simple LOL. Thanks for the helps guys!!

Comment: function parseDate( $tdate ) { $date = new DateTime( $date ); return explode( '-', $date->format( 'Y-F-d' ) ); } does the same, but easier.